# Cannot switch PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4

Tags: apache2, php

I'm trying to switch the PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4. I run the command below without success:

```sh
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then when I open a local webpage with the PHP info `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, the PHP version is still 8.0.3 and not 7.4.

Note that when I execute the command `sudo a2enmod php7.4` I get the following output:

```sh
dan@dan:~$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
Considering conflict php5 for php7.4:
Enabling module php7.4.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
```

Maybe is that the source of the issue?

Answer (score 9):

Do you have PHP5 installed on the system?

You can list all loaded Apache modules with `apache2ctl -M`:

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -M

Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

If you have multiple `php` versions, use `a2dismod` to disable the ones you do not need. From there, you can use `update-alternatives` to change the default version of PHP:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

> **Note:** Be sure to change `php7.4` to the version you wish to use.

Once this is done, restart the web server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should give you what you need.

Comment: worked like a charm thanks